# Compare letters of input string to list of vowels and output result by letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In below codes, the user can add any value. Then I have two different lists. I want to find if something is inside list 1 or in list 2 answer is true or false

```
#enter code here 
n= (input("enter any alphabate: "))
list1= ['a','e','i','o','u'];
list2 = ['A','E','I','O','U'];
for strng in (n):
 if n == list1 or n == list2:
    print("number is  vowel")
 else:
    print("number is not vowel")
```

Comment: `'a' == ['a','e','i','o','u']` is False. Consider why this might be.

Comment: for any alphabate output is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your code.

```
mystr = input("Enter any letters: ")

vowels = set('aeiou')

for idx, i in enumerate(mystr, 1):
    if i.lower() in vowels:
        print('{0}: Letter {1} is a vowel'.format(idx, i))
    else:
        print('{0}: Letter {1} is not a vowel'.format(idx, i))
```

**Explanation**

- It is good practice to use `set` for comparison as it yields O(1) complexity lookup.
- You can use `str.format()` to include your letter in a string.
- Convert to lower case so 2 sets of vowels are not required.
- Use `enumerate` to extract letter count.

This can be further shorted:

```
for idx, i in enumerate(mystr, 1):
    print('{0}: Letter {1} is{2}a vowel'\
          .format(idx, i, ' ' if i.lower() in vowels else ' not '))
```

Comment: What should I use if I want to check for any number that is in list or not but in a same way (user enter any number if it is in a list then it is true else false)(lst = [1,5,8,3];
if 5 in lst:
    print("5 is in list")--> it works fine but I want to modify it)

Comment: for integers you can compare to `set('0123456789')`. This is because `input()` by default returns a string.

Comment: I want to compare between user value which I enter manually and list value.(if number is present in a list then it gives true else false) I tried with compare to set('1345') but I am getting false for all values.

Comment: I tried-->n = (input("enter any number: "))
lst = [1,2,3,4,5];
if n in lst:
  print("number in a list")
else:
  print("not in a list")-- but it gives a same answer for every number

Comment: @Hadoopek, I suggest you start a new question - it's hard to see your code in comments.